# .data() gets the first list item's data attribute only?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Why is this code repeatedly getting the first data attribute only?

HTML

```
<ul class="als-wrapper">
    <li class="als-item"><a data-loc-subject="test value"><img src="http://www.ikea.com//us/en/images/products/pugg-wall-clock__13080_PE040801_S4.jpg" height="100" width="100"/></a>test value</li>
    <li class="als-item"><a data-loc-subject="a second value"><img src="http://www.ikea.com//us/en/images/products/pugg-wall-clock__13080_PE040801_S4.jpg" height="100" width="100"/></a>a second value</li>
    <li class="als-item"><a data-loc-subject="a third value"><img src="http://www.ikea.com//us/en/images/products/pugg-wall-clock__13080_PE040801_S4.jpg" height="100" width="100"/></a>a third value</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$( ".als-item" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $('.als-item a').data('loc-subject');
    alert(data);
});
```

[My jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/WebEnvelopment/H6XsV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `this` context and get the data attribute for the anchor inside each list element.

Instead of

```
var data = $('.als-item a').data('loc-subject');
```

try

```
var data = $(this).find('a').data('loc-subject');
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/H6XsV/9/)**

And use console.log for debugging purpose instead of an alert statement.